# How can I verify json response in Karate?

Tags: karate

I have one response like below
Below is print response -
[print] [
{
"status": "COMPLETED",
"Greeting": "Hello",
"API": "Rest",
}
]

Now I need to match response status whether it is COMPLETED or not

I tried below things but is not working.
And match response.status == 'COMPLETED'. Can I do this or I need to store this response first ?

And match response.status == 'COMPLETED
And match $ == {status:"FAILED"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip: when you see a `[]` that is a JSON array.

Try this:

```
* match response[0].status == 'COMPLETED'
```